# Art creativity in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

This is my friend's opion.
"Creativity/art means seeing something for the first time." Is the idea clearly and correctly expressed?

Comment: I must say no here because your meaning is entirely lost on me.

Comment: "Creativity" does not quite work because creativity is not restricted to the visual. For example, it is strained to say that you "see" music. "Art" works perfectly well so long as what is meant are "visual arts." To the extent that the sentence is awkward, it is the word "seeing" that makes it so. "Thinking of" may fit better.

Comment: Do you mean *ingenuity*?

Comment: Jeff Morrow,  that's right, my friend is talking about visual arts only.

Comment: Yes, DrMoishe Pippik.